# Is iphone development very similar to Mac OS X development?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

I'm learning (watching videos) on iphone development, and I am curious if this knowledge can be transfered to creating regular Mac OS X desktop applications?

i.e. is it MVC based also?  is allot of the framework carried over also?

Just a little confused between cocoa, iOS and if they overlap.

P.S what is the shortcut keys to launch an iphone app?  I can't figure out what that wierd symbol is.

Comment: your talking about Mac (as in Macintosh) not MAC (as in Media Access Control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In essence "yes". However, taking each of your questions in turn:

1. Whilst there's no UIKit classes on Mac OS X, the general development approach (and indeed a lot of the pure Cocoa class specifics) are identical. The run loop/event based nature of both systems are also effectively identical from a programming perspective.

   As such, time spent learning the iOS way of doing things will pay off if you go on to develop Mac OS X applications, as you'll know parts of the Cocoa framework and what you've learnt of the UIKit bits and pieces will transfer across to the Mac OS X's NSxxx equivalents.
2. iOS and Mac OS X Cocoa development are both MVC, although it really depends on the programmer to keep things "pure".

In terms of launching an iPhone app, I've no idea what you're talking about, but at a guess, the "weird" symbol could be the command (a.k.a.: "clover") key that's a standard part of all Mac keyboards. (A bit like the Windows key on Windows keyboards these days.)

Incidentally, there's some general Cocoa/Cocoa Touch information over on the [Apple site](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html), although this is fairly high level.

Comment: Also, if you obey the MVC principles in a Mac or iOS application, you can often make your model portable between the two OSs.  SQLite and Core Data are almost identical on the two platforms.

Answer (score 3):

iOS is the operating system (including the kernel, OS services, and the UI).  Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are mostly the UI layer libraries or frameworks.

Mac OS uses the Cocoa UI frameworks. iPhoneOS/iOS uses Cocoa Touch UI framework.  Both use (nearly) the same Objective C language and the same Foundation classes.

However, though the UI frameworks are similar in concept, they are not identical in terms of classes or "gotcha's".  So you will have to rewrite pretty much all the UI code of an app, but using a fairly parallel MVC style.

You will also need to learn how to do manual memory management in Cocoa Touch if you are used to taking advantage of the garbage collection enabled implementation of Obj C 2.0.

But if you know one framework, you will be able to pick up the other much more quickly than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Todd Ditchendorf has been developing [UMEKit](http://parsekit.com/umekit/), a Mac OS X framework for creating iPhone-like user interfaces in Cocoa desktop applications.